# Erro ao executar mysqli_query() em Select do BD

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Quando vou cadastrar algo no Banco de Dados da isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código PHP

```js
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../seguranca.php");
include_once("../conexao.php");
$nome_nivel     = $_POST["nome_nivel"];

$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO nivel_acessos (nome_nivel, created) VALUES ('$nome_nivel', NOW())");
?>
```

Conexão

```js
<?php
 $servidor = "localhost";
 $usuario = "root";
 $senha = "";
 $dbname = "tcc";
 
 //Criar a conexao
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa por a conexão no mysqli_query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO nivel_acessos (nome_nivel, created) VALUES ('$nome_nivel', NOW())");
```

Syntax:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"query");
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @rray corrigido ! rs